# Dynamic hosts with variables in ansible inventory by using python script

Tags: python, linux, ansible, pipe, lookup

I wanted to be able to make the ansible inventory look into the database to get the correct hosts to work on.

To make this work, I wrote a Python script that queries the host names from the database and prints it as yaml.

I ran a test to see if the pipe lookup plugin would be able to get the output:

```
$ ansible webservers -m debug -a "msg={{ lookup('pipe', './gather-hosts.py') }}"
{{ lookup('pipe', './gather-hosts.py') }} | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "web001:\n  descr: External websites\n  phpversion: 7.3\nweb002:\n  descr: External websites\n  phpversion: 7.3\nweb003:\n  descr: Internal websites\n  phpversion: 7.4\nweb004:\n  descr: Internal websites\n  phpversion: 7.4"
}
```

So this seems to work and I went to the next step, the hosts inventory file:

```
---
webservers:
  hosts: "{{ lookup('pipe', './gather-hosts.py') }}"
```

When I try to run this:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [webservers] *****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************
fatal: [{{ lookup('pipe', './gather-hosts.py') }}]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname {{ lookup('pipe', './gather-hosts.py') }}: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************
{{ lookup('pipe', './gather-hosts.py') }} : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

So instead of using the piped output as data for the webservers: group, it tries to connect with ssh onto a server called {{ lookup('pipe', ... }} which obviously won't work.

However, if I accidentally make a typo in the script filename, say call it gather--hosts.py, it will complain that it can't find the file, so it is actually interpreted but just not used to fill up the parent with its contents.

Anyone have a clue what I did wrong?

If it won't work like this, is there another way?

Note: I'm using ansible 2.10.2, python 3.8.6.

Note: If I strip out the variables and only output the hosts, it doesn't work either.

Comment: How about setting the host up as a variable in the playbook and then passing the hostname output from the Python script as a variable with -e $()

Comment: You're on the wrong track. This part of the inventory (i.e. any info that is not a var/fact) is not "templatable" as your tried. Either have your script output a full blown static inventory you can use directly, or go the [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#inventory-sources) route

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal, I don't understand what you mean, can you show me an example?

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, I didn't know this was possible! This may be even better for what I need. I'll try it out! Thanks!

Comment: @Zeitounator, "Either have your script output a full blown static inventory you can use directly", can you give me some more info on that? Should I create a script I call before calling ansible so that it creates an inventory file or is it possible to make ansible call the script for you?